# BUSCAR EL NIVEL DE UN NODO EN UN ARBOL BINARIO (NO DE BUSQUEDA)

Tags: java, recursión, busqueda, búsquedas, tree

he estado intentando buscar el nivel de un nodo en un arbol binario que no es de busqueda y contiene un caracter por nodo. Hice una funcion recursiva que consiste en recorrer el arbol con postorden pero solo funciona con los nodos que estan del lado izquierdo del arbol, cuando pasa al lado derecho, suma mas nodos de los que deberia. Si alguien puede ayudarme por favor, aqui les dejo mi codigo de la funcion mencionada.

```
private int nivel = 0;
private boolean val = false;

public void nivelNodo(NodoArbol raiz, char letra){
    if((raiz != null)&&(val == false)){
        if(raiz.getLetra() == letra){
            val = true;
        }
        else{
            if(raiz.getHijoIzq != null){
                nivel++;
                nivelNodo(raiz.getHijoIzq(), letra);
            }
            if(raiz.getHijoDer != null){
                nivel++;
                nivelNodo(raiz.getHijoDer(), letra);
                nivel--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: si tu árbol binario no es de búsqueda por el código :)

Comment: Cuál es el problema, devuelve un nivel incorrecto, no encuentra el nodo o... ? Igual como prueba a la variable 'nivel'  pásala como parámetro a nivelNodo().